# Понятно ли в данном предложении, что текст после двоеточия относится к первым, а не ко вторым?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Люди племени сан, встреченные здесь и на следующий день в деревне, отличаются от тех соплеменников, чьи фото украшают географические журналы и домашние коллекции интуристов: они носят одежду, похожую на «костюмы» наших отечественных бомжей.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, все понятно. Попутное замечание о стилистике. Плохо сочетают место и время ("здесь и на следующий день"). Так ли важно упоминать следующий день? Я бы изменил текст.

Вариант 1:  встреченные здесь и в деревне.
Вариант 2:  встреченные здесь и в деревне, которую мы посетили на следующий день.
Вариант 3:  встреченные здесь и, на следующий день, в деревне.

Comment: Вариант 1- не годится, потому что "в деревне" этого ещё нет, это будет лишь на следующий день. Вариант 2 - придется писать "которую я посетил на следующий день" ("я" можно удалить) А третий - не совсем понятно, чем по смыслу отличается от моего...?

Comment: В третьем варианте — однородные обстоятельства места  (здесь и в деревне), а "на следующий день" обособлено как дополнительная информация.

Comment: Прочитав Ваши замечания к ответу Jasmin, прихожу к выводу, что Вам важно указать, что встреча в деревне произошла на следующий день. Думаю, мой третий вариант подойдет Вам лучше всего.

Answer (score 1):

В качестве варианта:

Люди племени сан, **встреченные здесь и потом в деревне, носят одежду, похожую на «костюмы» наших отечественных бомжей, что явно отличает их от тех соплеменников,** чьи фото украшают географические журналы и домашние коллекции интуристов.

Comment: (1) Предложение такой структуры легче читать и понимать. (2) Замена на "потом" решает проблему совместимости обстоятельств, так как нет паузы (потом в дерЕвне)?

Comment: @Jasmin Звучит лучше. Но у вас "здесь и потом в деревне" сливается воедино, а в реальности - "в деревне" будет только на следующий день...  Я вообще не понимаю смысл: в деревне (здесь и потом); в деревне (там и сям) - так понятнее...  Наверное, после "здесь" нужна запятая?

Comment: По-моему, нормально читается, всё понятно. Но можно добавить "и потом УЖЕ в деревне". При очень большом желании можно обособить оборот и даже заключить его в скобки.